# Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-5000 using setResourceValue on Swift

Tags: swift

my question would be simple I am trying to add tags to some files in Finder using Swift and I am experiencing following error: `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-5000 "afpAccessDenied: Insufficient access privileges for operation "`

and here is my function to do that:

```
    for product in fetchedObjects
    {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: product.fileURLString!)

        print(product.fileNr)

        do
        {
            var tags = [String]()

            tags += ["test"]
            try url.setResourceValue(tags, forKey: URLResourceKey.tagNamesKey)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Maybe somebody could help me?

Comment: What is the path of the file you want to add the tag. Try to edit tags in the Downloads or User directory.

Comment: I am trying to access the in folder which is located in Desktop, already tried to to do that function in Downloads and User directories

Comment: Are you doing this in MacOS? The message means that you don't have permissions to add tags. Check the file permissions: in Finder, click on the file, then press CMD-I or right-click and select Get Info. In Terminal, do an `ls -l <filename>` in the directory containing the file.

Comment: yes, I am doing this on Mac. And I have read and write privileges, thats why I feel so frustrated about this error

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me with a single test file. Double-check your `product.fileURLString` value: try using SHIFT-CMD-G in Finder to see if the path takes you to the file.

Comment: Well, file exists :/ I checked it, I even made a method to do that, but still getting same error, even tried another Mac and also same error occurs. @leanne that code created a tag on your test file? I am so frustrated right now, been looking for solve of this issue for a few days, thats unusual

Comment: Post an example URL, so I can see what it looks like.

Comment: file:///Users/ernestasseputis/Desktop/study/finishoji%20copy.pptx

Comment: Weird question: what happens if you paste the file path into Terminal? Don't do anything with it - just paste it at a prompt to see what it looks like...

Comment: I created a new project and made same method again and I am not getting this error too, super weird

Comment: Sometimes non-printing characters get into some code - don’t know how - and cause things to go wonky. You can’t see these characters unless you copy the text into a hex editor, say. When I copied your example URL into Terminal, it appeared weirdly, so I suspect that was your case. Either way, I’m glad it’s working for you now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that, my app launched via xcode was using Sandbox mode. After turning it off in Capabilities everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you don't have authorization to access the files.

If you need to ask the user for admin permissions, you can take a look at the [`LocalAuthentication` framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication) (available in iOS 8+ and MacOS 10.10+).

The [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication) uses an [LAPolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy) of `deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics`, which requires TouchID or FaceID. Here's the same example allowing the user to authenticate with their password as well:

```
let myContext = LAContext()
let myLocalizedReasonString = <#String explaining why app needs authentication#>

var authError: NSError?
if #available(iOS 8.0, macOS 10.12.1, *) {
    if myContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {
        myContext.evaluatePolicy(. deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: myLocalizedReasonString) { success, evaluateError in
            if success {
                // User authenticated successfully, take appropriate action
            } else {
                // User did not authenticate successfully, look at error and take appropriate action
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Could not evaluate policy; look at authError and present an appropriate message to user
    }
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```